# The sample of Android's MultiClientInputMethod cannot properly work

Tags: android, android-input-method

I follow Google's official instructions to use the example of MultiClientInputMethodManagerService(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/inputmethod/multi-client-ime.md)

The AOSP11 emulator with perDisplayFocus has been built, the screenshot you can see that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lldaR.png)

But the ime's window only shows on main display, and can only input on the main display[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Vq0.png)

I have added some log to see the multi input window , it seems like has shown

```
@Override
public void onShowSoftInput(int flags, ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onShowSoftInput clientId=" + mClientId + " flags=" + flags);
    }
    final SoftInputWindow window =
            mSoftInputWindowManager.getSoftInputWindow(mSelfReportedDisplayId);
    if (window == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mClientId != window.getClientId()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onShowSoftInput() from a background client is ignored."
                + " windowClientId=" + window.getClientId()
                + " clientId=" + mClientId);
        return;
    }

    window.show();
    Log.v(TAG, "is showing"+window.isShowing());
}
```

The logcat of AndroidStudio [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unwzI.png)
I search on Google and has not found relevant questions for a long time.Has anyone used this ,thank you very much for the experienced answerers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had solved it , anyone who sees this problem can refer to my solution https://github.com/Superpengun/MultiDisplayInput

The jar used in the project is extracted from the aosp12 compiled classed.jar ，the keyboardview is a dialog,maybe there is a difference of dialog's Multi-screen display. In the github's project i rebuild the jar for hidden api of AOSP12 and verfied it